# Creating a Gallery in Java - Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, directory, image-gallery

I don't know very much about Java (I know the basics). I want to create an Image Gallery with Netbeans, but I have absolutely no clue how to do this.

What I want to do:

The User should see all Images inside a specified folder (as thumbs) and should be able to view it in "original size" upon clicking on the Photo. Also (via a Button) he should be able to "transfer" an Image file to that folder.

So basically I have a database of misc. articles, each article has some Images in a unique folder on the Filesystem (eg. /images/art_01), I want to display all images within this folder and have the possibility to add (speaking, copying) new Images into this folder (there is no need to delete an Image) arranged, so it doesn't look too disgusting ;).

Since I just now the basics of Java, I qould appreciate if someone could help me, with something I can adapt directly into a JFrame - if that's possible.

Thanks ;)

Comment: To be honest, nothing, because I don't have a clue how to do this. I could put a lot of jLabels on there and define the icon, but that way I'm limiting the amount of pictures...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With netbeans it's really easy, netbeans has a JFrame/JPanel drag&drop designer/gui builder (right click on package -> new -> JFrame form). After customizing the GUI you can make your main class extend your custom frame, or add a new custom panel to your JFrame, depending on whether you choose to make a JFrame or a JPanel.

http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/quickstart-gui.html some details on how to use the netbeans gui builder.

With this builder you can also add events to the different components. If you want to view a directory use JFileChooser.

Comment: I have the main UI designed in Netbeans - I just need this specific part ;)

Comment: Maybe use JFileChooser? I think that's in the GUI builder as well.

Comment: If it's possible to "limit" the JFileChooser so you cannot move out and only see the images, that would be kind-of a solution ;)

Comment: You can use FileFilter to limit it to only see images, as for moving out I'm not sure right now, still checking through the api.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html#advancedexample looks like an image selecting example...as for not being able to move out you I suppose you could just check if the directory has changed from the desired directory and then change it to that desired directory, which would be the "hack" method...don't blame you if you don't like that method